# Disabling the 5 GhZ wifi band on the HTC One X

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, htc-one-x

I had some wifi connection dropping issues with my One X. I don't appear to have the "[you're holding it wrong](http://www.theverge.com/2012/6/18/3094567/htc-one-x-wi-fi-hardware-connectivity-issues)" issue (the [squeeze test](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688538) comes out negative), but some googling [found](http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-1636000.html) that there seem to be issues with 5 GhZ WiFi bands as well.

It eventually turned out to be some sort of known incompatibility between the One X and my router's firmware (a router update fixed it), but in the process of testing, I tried to disable 5 GhZ WiFi. However I had to disable the 5 GhZ band on my WiFi router (and thus disable it for all my devices) because I couldn't find a way to disable it on the phone.

A posting in the thread above contains

> In the WiFi settings, under the menu, "WiFi Network Bands", select "2.4 GHz only".

However I cannot find such a setting. Am I just blind? Or is there at least another way to disable 5 GhZ on a (non-branded, non-rooted) One X?

Comment: Where exactly are you looking? I have what appears to be the same option on my Galaxy Nexus if I go into the Wi-Fi settings, press the overflow menu (the "three dots" button) and select "Advanced". It's listed as "Wi-Fi frequency band". Maybe getting a screenshot of what you see in your settings would be useful if you can do it (does `Volume Down + Power` work on the One X?).

Comment: @eldarerathis Yes, screenshot works on One X (didn't that finally make it into a standard Android feature?). Anyway, I did check there; this is all I see behind the advanced wifi settings: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NCQbE.png

Comment: Yes, it's standard in ICS, but I don't know if some manufacturers decided to move/alter it. Maybe the setting that others are seeing is due to carrier/regional differences in firmware or something. That would be fairly annoying if it's the case.

Comment: After some reading it appears that HTC has released an update to fix some Wi-Fi issues, but I'm not sure if it will necessarily fix your problem.

Comment: Can you please identify what you mean by "non-branded, non-rooted"...? Where/how did you get this phone? What network is it on? What possible version of this phone do you have that does not have these settings?

Comment: @Wartickler non-branded = I didn't get it from a carrier, I just bought it at the store (I don't know about the US, but here in Germany you don't have to get your phone from your carrier). non-rooted = I didn't root it.

Comment: Right, sorry (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this was just a bug; this option re-appeared in the "Advanced" Wi-Fi settings after one of the OTA updates.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this review of the Wi-fi capabilities of the HTC One X from anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5779/htc-one-x-for-att-review/7) it would appear that the option is there. Look two-thirds of the way down on the site and see this image:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; image taken from AnandTech)</sub>

[image: IMG: image from anandtech]

Comment: The international One X doesn't have that setting (I'm looking at mine right now). It may be that the US/LTE version doesn't have it either.

Comment: Can you resize that image? :)

Comment: Hmmm...it comes from the website. I'll see what I can do (: